# Tcl greedy subexpression difference between + and *

Tags: regex, tcl, regex-greedy

I am trying to understand Tcl subexpression matches and "greediness" and am completely stumped as to what's going on.  Referencing the example found at http://wiki.tcl.tk/396:

```
%regexp -inline (.*?)(n+)(.*) ennui
en e n {} 
%regexp -inline ^(.*?)(n+)(.*)$ ennui
ennui e nn ui
```

Notwithstanding the fact that I don't completely understand "nested expressions" (that is what the parenthesis indicate, right?) matching, I decided to start small and just try the difference between * and + as greedy operators:

```
% regexp -inline (.*)(u*)(.*) ennui
ennui ennui {} {}
% regexp -inline (.*)(u+)(.*) ennui
ennui enn u i
```

If * matches zero or more, and + matches one or more, I don't understand the difference in the output between the two commands. Why do u* and u+ produce two different results on the same string?

I feel like this is an extremely important nuance - that if I can grasp what's going on in this simple pattern match/regex, my life will be made whole.  Help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the `(.*)(u*)(.*)` and `(.*)(u+)(.*)` difference is that the second regex *requires at least 1 `u`*.

The ARE regex in Tcl uses backtracking (as most NFAs). With `(.*)`, the engine grabs the whole string from the beginning to end, and starts backtracking to find if it can accommodate for the next subpattern.

In the first expression, `u` is optional (can be 0 due to `*`), thus, the greedy `.*` decides it won't yield any characters. Then, the  last `.*` can also match 0 characters, again, no need to give any characters to that group.

In the second expression, the `u` is obligatory, must occur at least once. Thus, the engine grabs all the string with the first `.*`, then backtracks, and founds `u`. So, it puts the starting sequence to group 1, and matches and captures `u`  with `(u+)`. Since `u` is only 1, the last `(.*)` matches and captures the rest of the string.

Comment: Excellent!  Your explanation is very enlightening.  I've spent about an hour since reading your reply trying different combinations of patterns and what used to confuse me is now explainable.  **Thank you** for the excellent reply!

Comment: If you have trouble understanding the first case (the quoted example with mixed greediness),have a look at [Interaction Between Quantifiers with Different Greediness](http://wiki.tcl.tk/396): *All quantifiers in a branch get switched to the same greediness, so adding a non-greedy quantifier makes the other quantifiers in the branch implicitly non-greedy as well.* Also, you may find this [Henry Spencer's post](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/comp.lang.tcl/FddeFPbTFw8/asoMuv7dWqIJ) of interest.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the non-greediness. Tcl regular expressions have a quirk: the *first* quantifier in the expression sets the greediness for the *whole* expression. (See the "Matching" section of the [`re_syntax` manual page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M95), paying close attention to the word "*preference*"):

> A branch has the same preference as the first quantified atom in it which has a preference.

```
%regexp -inline (.*?)(n+)(.*) ennui
en e n {}
```

- `(.*?)` grabs zero or more characters, preferring the shortest match
- `(n+)` grabs one or more `n`, inheriting the shortest preference
- `(.*)` grabs zero or more characters, inheriting the shortest preference

The first subexpression matches from the first character up to but not including the first `n`. The 2nd part matches one `n`. The 3rd part matches zero characters between the first and the second `n`.

I'm a bit surprised that the first subexpression captured an `e` instead of capturing zero characters before the first `n`, but that can be explained by the higher priority of "leftmost" matching to the regex engine:

> In the event that an RE could match more than one substring of a given string, the RE matches the one starting earliest in the string.

The achored expression's results surprises me too: I would have expected `e n nui` instead of `e nn ui`. Adding the `$` anchor seems to have discarded the expression's preference for shortest matching.

Answer (score 0):

@stribizhev answer pretty much explains everything. As for your non-greedy version  — the question mark at end tells the engine that it shouldn't consume the whole string, but grab the least possible match and continue from there.

- `(.*?) for "ennui"` matches 0 characters and it's ok, since we're not greedy
- `(n+) for "ennui"` match fails, so the engine returns to matching `(.*?)` again
- `(.*?) for "ennui"` now matches one character `e`
- `(n+) for "nnui"` matches `nn` since its greedy
- `(.*) for "ui"` matches whats left, `ui`